# How to access folder files located from other domain folder located inside the public-html?

Tags: html, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

I want to access the image folder which is located in (e.g "example.com/images/one.jpg").
I have created the subdomain named (e.g "subdomain.example.com").
Both domain folders are in same public_html.
How i can authoize my subdomain, which can access files using htaccess rules or anything else. i tired this "../../" before file name, but not working.

Note: i dont want to put a whole path to access the files from root domain, such as https://......

Thanks

Comment: "i tired this "../../" before file name" - why? You stated earlier that "Both domain folders are in same public_html". (?) " i dont want to put a whole path to access the files from root domain, such as https://......" - why not? That's exactly what you do need to do, if "both domain folders are in the same public_html". Can you clarify the filesystem paths that the main domain and subdomain point to?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers deal in URLs, not the paths on your filesystem.

It sounds like you have configured your server so that the images are only available on `example.com` and are not available on `subdomain.example.com`.

You therefore need to tell the browser to access the images from the other hostname.

```
src="//example.com/images/one.jpg"
```

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. I did a little bit of server configuration in the .htaccess file. I write the rule that no image can be publicly accessible. but I want to authorize my subdomain which can access the image URL. please do let me know how I can rewrite the rule so the subdomain has the same privileges to access the files of the root domain. Note: both domains are in the same public_html directory, but when I tried to access the image of the root domain it shows a forbidden error to access the file. Thanks

Comment: @ZeeshanAli So what rule did you add to `.htaccess` that prevented any image to be publicly accessible? (Please edit your question with this information.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a domain.com and sub.domain.com, these are two completely different paths. You cannot get data from each other using reference as path like `'../images/foo.png'`.

In this case, you have to put all the path `https://www.sub.domain.com/images/foo.png`. This is the same way you need to do when uses a subdomain as resource in order to decrease the number of request in your website for images and sources in general.

Comment: "these are two completely different paths" - but the OP does state "Both domain folders are in same public_html"?

Comment: @MrWhite — filesystem paths and URLs paths are not the same thing

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I get that. But I realise now we may be talking at cross purposes - I'm referring to the filesystem path that the hosts point to, not the URL. (Although the _URL-path_ must also be the same in both cases since the two hosts would appear to point to the same directory on the filesystem.)

Comment: Current rules in my parent domain "example.com" 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/ [NC] RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|mov|mkv|flv|svg)$ - [F,L] RewriteEngine On  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` 

Shall i add your code in the top of the code? i tried but not working. can you please edit the rules & attach the code in comment please?

Answer (score 0):

> I did a little bit of server configuration in the .htaccess file. I write the rule that no image can be publicly accessible. but I want to authorize my subdomain which can access the image URL.
> :
> Note: both domains are in the same public_html directory

You would seem to require an *exception* for the subdomain and block *other* hostnames?

It's a bit of a guess how you are currently doing this - either with mod_authz_core and a `<FilesMatch>` container perhaps? Or using mod_rewrite? Or an Apache `<If>` expression??

You could do something like the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of the root `.htaccess` file to block access to all images, except when accessed via the subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block (403 Forbidden) all image requests unless accessed through the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.example\.com
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|webp|gif)$ - [F]
```

Now, a request of the form `https://example.com/images/one.jpg` will be blocked, but `https://subdomain.example.com/images/one.jpg` will be accessible.

> i dont want to put a whole path to access the files from root domain

But you will need to use an absolute (or protocol-relative) URL to access the files from the *subdomain*.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Current rules in my parent domain "example.com"
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/ [NC]
> RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|mov|mkv|flv|svg)$ - [F,L]
>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

Ah, so you've implemented a form of hotlink protection! In that case you would seem to just need to modify the first condition to allow requests *from* the subdomain as well. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(subdomain\.)?example.com/
```

To allow requests *from* both `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`. The `NC` flag should be omitted. All *browsers* will lowercase the hostname in the request.

No other rules are required to "allow" access. You do not need to use the absolute URL to access these resources - since that does not appear to be what you are blocking. You simply need to be able to access these resources *from* another host (ie. the subdomain).

**In summary:**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Hotlink protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(subdomain\.)?example.com/
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|mov|mkv|flv|svg)$ - [F]

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `L` flag is not required with the `F` flag, since it is *implied*.

The `^(.*)$` is unnecessary since the backreference is not being used. Simply having `^` is sufficient and more efficient - to be successful for everything without having to actually *match* everything.

Comment: I added this rule in .htaccess file but still not working.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli You need to _change_ your existing rule(s), not simply "add" it. Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file and include how you are currently restricting access.

Comment: Current rules in my parent domain "example.com"

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|mov|mkv|flv|svg)$ - [F,L]
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`


Shall i add your code in the top of the code? i tried but not working. can you please edit the rules & attach the code in comment please?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Ah, you've implemented "hotlink protection". This rule needs to be _modified_ (nothing extra needs to be added). I've updated my answer.

Comment: I added your updated code in my .htaccess file but still i cant access the images using complete URL in my php code (e.g https://example.com/image/foo.jpg). 
i want my folder images of parent domain which is "example.com" is accessable in both parent & subdomain. i created subdomain for admin portal to check the user images which are stored in parent domain folder. images still accessable in parent domain & working fine, also the link forbidden error correctly when someone open the image link directly in new tab.

Comment: my main concern is that, i can access the parent domain folder images in my subdomain through php code. please rewrite the .htaccess rule & allow subdomain to access the parent domain images folder. i copy pasted your .htaccess code but still not working. you are the only one who can resolve this issue accurately.

Comment: root directory: example.com/images/foo.jpg
subdomain: subdomain.example.com

i want to access the images contained in parent domain using php code in subdomain admin portal. also want to deny access to these images from public. only authorized subdomain can access the images through php code.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli "I added your updated code in my .htaccess file" - You mean, you _replaced_ your existing code with the code I provided? "using complete URL in my **php code**" - You didn't say you were trying to access these images from (server-side) PHP?! Don't you mean (client-side) "HTML"?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli "my main concern is that, i can access the parent domain folder images in my subdomain through **php code**." - Ok, you're losing me here? How does PHP fit into the picture? You can't restrict access to server-side PHP code, except by making fundamental changes to the server config. This can't be done in `.htaccess` (unless you are making HTTP requests using PHP - but you shouldn't be making HTTP requests using PHP!?).

Comment: @ZeeshanAli If you remove the `.htaccess` file entirely does it "work"??